# How to start new chapters on the right hand side

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, chapters, report, double-sided

I use the `report` document class, and I would like that chapters always start on the right hand side, anyone an idea how this could be easily done?

Answer (score 57):

Use `\documentclass[twoside,openright]{report}`. (The `openright` class option without `twoside` will not suffice, as LaTeX views every page as "right" page in `oneside` mode.)

Comment: all right, but how to avoid displaying of numeration on this sites...?

Comment: i found it: `\usepackage{emptypage}`

Comment: Does `openright` only work for `report`? I use `scrreprt` and it does not seem to work.

Comment: @Socrates KOMA-Script is a more advanced documentclass and its options are defined as key=value pairs, indeed in the documentation can be read "headings=openany", or "headings=openright" etc for this setting.