# \includepdf changes left and right pages

Tags: sectioning, double-sided, printing

I've followed advice at "[How to start new chapters on the right hand side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6227/how-to-start-new-chapters-on-the-right-hand-side)" and found that including as title page, one PDF page is braking left&right orientation:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[pdftex,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\includepdf{onetitlepage.pdf}   % <---- problem
\begin{abstract}
Abstract \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{CH1}
\lipsum[2-6]
\chapter{CH2}
\lipsum[7-8]
\chapter{CH3}
\lipsum[9]
\end{document}
```

After including one page PDF, I get same document, but with one more page on beginning. It's all right except one thing: right pages are now left pages.

My current workaround is to include additional empty page, like that:

```
\includepdf{onetitlepage.pdf}
\includepdf{oneemptypage.pdf}   % <---- current solution
```

Is is LaTeX-y way?

Can it be done in more elegant, LaTeX-y way?

What is the reason why including `onepage.pdf` breaks left&right hand side,
and how to prevent it when writing documents?

Comment: BTW: You don't need an additional empty PDF file, specifying `\includepdf[pages={1,{}}]{onetitlepage.pdf}` (the `{}` creates a blank page) is enough - however, [egreg's solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44955/3323) is the far better approach.

Comment: Thanks, your advice help me as well, because I don't want to have second page blank with "2" on bottom - instead, I prefer to have whole page empty.

Comment: However there is alternative solution for preventing header&footer : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1681/how-to-remove-head-and-footlines-for-pages-between-chapters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put `\cleardoublepage` after `\includepdf`. Also, specify the `notitlepage` option, so the abstract will not start anew the page numbering.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\includepdf{onetitlepage.pdf}
\cleardoublepage

\begin{abstract}
Abstract \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{CH1}
\lipsum[2-6]
\chapter{CH2}
\lipsum[7-8]
\chapter{CH3}
\lipsum[9]
\end{document}
```

*Never* specify the `pdftex` option (there are cases where it's necessary, though, in connection with `geometry` and `crop`, but it's not your case).

Comment: Thanks. Till now I've been using `\cleardoublepage` before chapters. Now I know it's useful *after* some commands.

Comment: `notitlepage` help :). I didn't knew before how to deal with page reset on abstract :)

Comment: Unfortunately ones I switched to `notitlepage` my margins and space between lines is lost. I've made question rising this issue: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45105/after-notitlepage-my-abstract-lost-formatting .