# After notitlepage my abstract lost formatting

Tags: formatting, titles, abstract

I've added `notitlepage` option to not get my page counter reset ( according to suggestion : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44955/7128 )

but my abstract lost formatting !

Now it has line spacing and margins like rest of document.

*How to achieve default look of abstract when `notitlepage` option is used?*

```
\documentclass[pdftex,a4paper,12pt,twoside,openany]{report}
%\documentclass[pdftex,a4paper,12pt,twoside,openany,notitlepage]{report} % <--- switch to this to see difference
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\linespread{1.6} % interline 2.0
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{abstract}
\chapter{CH}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

How to achieve same look of abstract with `notitlepage` as without that option, wile preserving same formatting of rest of document ?

Comment: `$ texdef -t latex 'abstract'` command returns: `\abstract:
\long macro:->\if@twocolumn \section *{\abstractname }\else \small \begin {center}{\bfseries \abstractname \vspace {-.5em}\vspace {\z@ }}\end {center}\quotation \fi ` - it looks like sth I'm looking for. Advice how to apply this?

Comment: Would you please show a MWE?

Comment: Done: Added MWE. It shows linespread issue. I haven't managed to show margins issue in MWE. As I will find out how to do this, I will add it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow you. You *do* get enlarged line spacing and reduced margin with the `notitlepage` option. Better using the `setspace` package for playing with the leading.

Comment: How to achieve same look of abstract with notitlepage as without, wile preserving same formatting of rest of document ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\renewenvironment{abstract}
  {\newpage\thispagestyle{plain}
   \null\vfil
   \begin{center}%
     \bfseries \abstractname
   \end{center}}
  {\par\vfil\null\cleardoublepage}
```

Comment: Great, Thank you. Now my document builds right again :)