# In Lyx how do I get chapters to start on odd pages

Tags: sectioning, lyx, chapters, double-sided

I'm using Lyx and I want the pdf output to print Contents, new chapters and bib on a odd page. How can I do this?

What information do you require from lyx?
Class is Report.

---

> Document > Configuration > Document class > Class options > write
>   twoside,openright > Check that source code (view menu) start with
>   \documentclass[english,twoside,openright]{report} – Fran

We are almost there! 
Now My layout is

1. Title Page
2. Abstract // I'd want this on page 2.
3. Blank (pg2)
4. Contents (pg3)
5. Blank (pg4)
6. Chapter 1 (pg5)

What I really want is

1. Title Page
2. Blank  <<<< EXTRA BLANK Page
3. Abstract (p2)
4. Blank (pg3)
5. Contents (pg4)
6. Blank (pg5)
7. Chapter 1 (pg6)

What info do you need?

---

Okay I've found a solution.

I inserted Latex code (⌘L) `\cleardoublepage{}`  before Abstract now it is beautiful!

Comment: Try adding `twoside,openright` to the document class options.

Comment: Duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6227/how-to-start-new-chapters-on-the-right-hand-side I suppose?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. This question is how to pipe that answer in the GUI Lyx. I'm new to Latex and currently I'd like to stay within my GUI.

Comment: Document > Configuration > Document class > Class options > write `twoside,openright` > Check that source code (view menu) start with `\documentclass[english,twoside,openright]{report}`

Comment: "\documentclass[twoside,british,twoside,openright]{report}"

Comment: Wow, we are almost there! The chapters are on the left page.
However left page is ODD. Currently I have Title page, Abstract page, blank pg2, contents pg3, blank pg4, chpt 1 pg5.... ect

Comment: I think my abstract is the issue, What info do you guys need?

Comment: Reduce (a copy of) your document to a minimal example, i.e. just the smallest amount of content necessary to demonstrate the unwanted behaviour. Then add either the exported LaTeX source or the contents of the .lyx-file itself (it is a plain text file, open it in a text editor, e.g. notepad, and you'll see) to your question.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. thanks I think I've sussed it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer from Fran:

> Document > Configuration > Document class > Class options > write twoside,openright > Check that source code (view menu) start with \documentclass[english,twoside,openright]{report} – Fran

In my case I also had to inserted Latex code (⌘L) `\cleardoublepage{}` before my abstract.

---

Amendment: I changed Abstract to an unnumbered chapter and removed `\cleardoublepage{}` because the previous action caused unusual page numbering before abstract page.

Answer (score 0):

as in [this link](http://lyx.475766.n2.nabble.com/Starting-chapters-on-right-hand-page-td476132.html) you don't need to change class settings, just go to

Document->Settings->Page Layout->Two-sided document

(the "openright" option is not needed, it is default).

you need after that to use: `clear double page` seperator between the chapters