# In Lyx how do I fix the border shift for binding?

Tags: lyx, margins, double-sided

WIth regards to piping answers into Lyx GUI, I am continuing the my question from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166321/in-lyx-how-do-i-get-chapters-to-start-on-odd-pages?noredirect=1#comment382111_166321).

The layout of chapters starting on the odd pages appears to be correct, however the shift left or right I believe to compensate for the binding of the pages appears to be shifting TOWARDS the binding, should it be shifting away from the binding? how can I fix this.

Observe the binding side has a smaller margin...
[image: PDF image]

Expand the loerem ipsoms to but here is what i have in my `.lyx` file.

```
#LyX 2.0 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 413
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass report
\options openright,twoside
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language british
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman default
\font_sans default
\font_typewriter default
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100

\graphics default
\default_output_format pdf2
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref true
\pdf_keywords "Software Diversity, Monoculture,Security, Randomising,Randomizing, Java, Data Structures, ANTRL4, ANTLR"
\pdf_bookmarks true
\pdf_bookmarksnumbered false
\pdf_bookmarksopen false
\pdf_bookmarksopenlevel 1
\pdf_breaklinks false
\pdf_pdfborder false
\pdf_colorlinks false
\pdf_backref false
\pdf_pdfusetitle true
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_amsmath 1
\use_esint 1
\use_mhchem 1
\use_mathdots 1
\cite_engine basic
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 2
\tocdepth 2
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 2
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Title
Front Title Page
\end_layout

\begin_layout Author
Author
\end_layout

\begin_layout Date
Date
\end_layout

\begin_layout Chapter*
Abstract
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
My Abstract
\end_layout

\begin_layout Chapter*
Acknowledgements
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
my ack
\end_layout

\begin_layout Chapter
the first chapter
\end_layout

\begin_layout Section
lorem ipsom lorem 
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
ipsom lorem ipsom……
\end_layout



\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset CommandInset bibtex
LatexCommand bibtex
btprint "btPrintAll"
bibfiles "/myPath/here"
options "bibtotoc,plain"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: It is correct that the binding side has the smaller margin. See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42063/illogical-twoside-margins?lq=1

Comment: @TorbjørnT. oh! :| (trying to not look stupid...) thanks. At least I wasn't the only one confused by the margins.

Comment: I suppose we could rather close it as a duplicate, if you agree?

Comment: Yeah I'll agree to that.